# How can I get a ril serial number for Motorola MOTO X?

Tags: android

I was making an application to get a ril serial number.
In Samsung works fine!! but, tested in Motorola MOTO X it doesn't show anything!

The code I'm using is this:

```
String serial = null; 

            try {
                 Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
                 Method get = c.getMethod("get", String.class);
                 serial = (String) get.invoke(c, "ril.serialnumber");
             } catch (Exception ignored) {
             }
```

Comment: you're using a private API via reflection - are you surprised this doesn't work on all devices? Clearly, Samsung and Motorola customize their source code, and the mileage of reflection like this will vary by device.

Comment: ok, but where can I get Motorola MOTO X API?? or where can I consult that?