# Fixed identifier for a machine (uuid.getnode)

Tags: python, hardware, uuid, identifier, mac-address

I'm trying to find something I can use as a unique string/number for my script that is fixed in a machine and easily obtainable(cross-platform). I presume a machine would have a network card. I don't need it to be really unique, but the necessary is it should be fixed in a long run and as rare as possible.

I know MAC can be changed and I'd probably make a warning about it in my script, however I don't expect anyone to change MAC each morning.

What I came up with is `uuid.getnode()`, but in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html) there is:

> If all attempts to obtain the hardware address fail, we choose a random 48-bit number

Does it mean that for each function call I get another random number, therefore it's not possible to use it if MAC is unobtainable?

> ...on a machine with multiple network interfaces the MAC address of any one of them may be returned.

Does this sentence mean `getnode()` gets a random(or first) MAC from all available? What if it'd get MAC A in first run and MAC B next time? There'd be no problem if I'd get a fixed list(sort, concatenate, tadaaa!)

I'm asking because I have no way how to test it myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to test the first part on my android device and on each new python run it created random number, so it's not usable at all for this purpose.

The second problem kind of drowned itself, because if in the docs it mentioned that it may return `any one of them`, then it's not something you could rely on (+I couldn't find a machine I could test it on). A nice package `netifaces` came to rescue, which does a similar thing

```
netifaces.interfaces() # returns e.g. ['lo', 'eth0', 'tun2']

netifaces.ifaddresses('eth0')[netifaces.AF_LINK]
# returns [{'addr': '08:00:27:50:f2:51', 'broadcast': 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff'}]
```

However I rather gave up using MACs, I got something rather more stable.

*Now to the identifiers:*

**1) Windows:**

Executing this one and getting output may be good enough:

```
wmic csproduct get UUID
```

or the one I used and is available in registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography`):

```
import _winreg
registry = _winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
address = 'SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography'
keyargs = _winreg.KEY_READ | _winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY
key = _winreg.OpenKey(registry, address, 0, keyargs)
value = _winreg.QueryValueEx(key, 'MachineGuid')
_winreg.CloseKey(key)
unique = value[0]
```

**2) Linux:**

```
/sys/class/dmi/id/board_serial
```

or

```
/sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid
```

or if not root:

```
cat /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
```

**3) Android:**

If you are working with python and don't want to mess with Java stuff, then this should work pretty good:

```
import subprocess
cmd = ['getprop', 'ril.serialnumber']
self.unique = subprocess.check_output(cmd)[:-1]
```

but if you like Java, then go for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2785493/5994041) although even `ANDROID_ID`'s uniqueness is rather debatable if it's allowed to change, therefore a serial number is most likely a safer bet.

Note that like it's already mentioned in the linked answer, even `ril.serialnumber` can be null/empty or non-existing (missing key). Same thing happens even with the official [Android API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#SERIAL) where it's clearly stated this:

> A hardware serial number, **if available.**

**Mac/iPhone:**
I couldn't find any solution as I don't have access to any of these, but if there is a variable that holds the machine id value, then you should be able to get there with simple `subprocess.check_output()`

Comment: I am unable to get android uuid with this code. I'm using Android marshmallow and installed terminal emulator on it I can see full list of `getprop` but `ril.serialnumber` is not exist. does it needs root permission?

Comment: @Gahan see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368423/how-can-i-get-a-ril-serial-number-for-motorola-moto-x#comment43189061_27368423) for why is that hapenning. It's rather unfortunate, but for all of the methods to get a unique device identifier you should also have a "backup plan" i.e. maybe throw some file/string to a hash function or a similar thing. If you're using [Kivy](http://kivy.org/), you can access Android API directly with [pyjnius](https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/)(it needs JNI).

Comment: I am not using kivy. however I have python to work with all it's default module it comes with such as uuid,os,sys,subprocess etc. any other module is not available for the existing cross compilation I am using.

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't recommend using a MAC address for a unique machine identifier, since it can change depending on the network being used. Rather, I'd recommend using the machine's native GUID, assigned by the operating system during install. I wrote a small, cross-platform PyPI package that queries a machine's native GUID called [py-machineid](https://pypi.org/project/py-machineid/).

Essentially, it looks like this, but with some Windows-specific WMI registry queries for more a accurate ID. The package also has support for hashing the ID, to anonymize it.

```py
import subprocess
import sys

def run(cmd):
  try:
    return subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, capture_output=True, check=True, encoding="utf-8") \
                     .stdout \
                     .strip()
  except:
    return None

def guid():
  if sys.platform == 'darwin':
    return run(
      "ioreg -d2 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | awk -F\\\" '/IOPlatformUUID/{print $(NF-1)}'",
    )

  if sys.platform == 'win32' or sys.platform == 'cygwin' or sys.platform == 'msys':
    return run('wmic csproduct get uuid').split('\n')[2] \
                                         .strip()

  if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
    return run('cat /var/lib/dbus/machine-id') or \
           run('cat /etc/machine-id')

  if sys.platform.startswith('openbsd') or sys.platform.startswith('freebsd'):
    return run('cat /etc/hostid') or \
           run('kenv -q smbios.system.uuid')
```

Comment: hello @ezekg, will this always return the same value? i am working on a similar project in which i need to get a unique "machine" id, i considered using the uuid.getnode() but as the original author of this thread mentioned, it doesn't always return the same value, sometimes it returns the actual MAC (whether it be wireless or wired) but sometimes it returns an interface mac. so its unreliable , my question is if your method is reliable ? does it always return the same mac ?

Comment: @KhalylEbdelli this solution has nothing to do with a MAC. This uses the operating system's unique identifier, typically set during OS installation.

Answer (score 2):

For **Mac/iphone** you can try below command:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output("ioreg -rd1 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | grep -E '(UUID)'", shell=True).split('"')[-2] # for me i got it on list value -2 if having any trouble try getting it with any alternative list element.
```

Comment: python3 returns bytes, need to decode this to a str or pass bytes to .split()

Answer (score 1):

`uuid.getnode` will return the same value for every call wthinin a single run of your app. If it has to defer to the random algorithm, then you will get a different value when you start a new instance of your app.

The implementation for `getNode` shows why. This is sort of what the routine looks like in python 3.7 (comments mine, code simplified for clarity)

```
_node = None

def getnode():

    global _node
    if _node is not None:
        # Return cached value
        return _node

    # calculate node using platform specific logic like unix functions, ifconfig, etc 
    _node = _get_node_from_platform()
    if not _node:
        # couldn't get node id from the system. Just make something up
        _node = _get_random_node() 
    return _node
```